# How to decouple a Java application from the console during runtime

Tags: java, cmd

I have a Java Swing application that is launched from Windows command line. This application displays a Swing window and exits when the user closes the window.

What I want is to print to Windows console a couple of messages using `System.out` then return from Windows console so I can close it with the application still running in background.

When running the application with `java -jar ...` I cannot close the Windows console without closing the application, while `javaw -jar ...` decouples the application from the console and no message is printed.

Is there a solution to decouple the Java application from the console during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try adding "&" at the end of the command. This will move the application running at the background and still the logs would be printed.

Eg. assume your jar name is abc.jar

try

```
java -jar abc.jar &
```

Comment: The & makes the command run in the background on Unix based system only (not Windows). Anyway, it does not solve decoupling the Java application from the console during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> `FreeConsole`
> The FreeConsole function detaches the calling process from
> its console.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole